# What am I doing wrong with creating a java package and importing it (beginner)?

Tags: java, package, access-control, subdirectory

I'm learning Java from a book and am on the chapter about access control. The exercise asks me to create a class in a package and then create an instance of that class outside of the package.

All of my files have been created in a folder that is located at:
Users/myname/Desktop/java/accessControl and I am on a mac if that matters

I created a file Person.java with this code:

```
package net.baumli.a;

public class Person {
    void welcome() {
        System.out.println("A new person has entered the room, welcome.");
    }
}
```

I don't have a domain name so I just used net.mylastname and created that package name at random.

Then I created the file AcTest.java

```
import net.baumli.a.Person;

public class AcTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person mike = new Person();
        mike.welcome();
    }
}
```

and then I compile javac AcTest.java 
and receive these errors :

```
cTest.java:1: error: package net.baumli.a does not exist
import net.baumli.a.Person;
               ^

AcTest.java:5: error: cannot access Person
               Person mike = new Person();
            ^

bad source file: ./Person.java

file does not contain class Person

Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
```

2 errors

Do I need to change my CLASSPATH variable? I know it says my class isn't in the right sub directory but how do i get it there? When I create a package name, is it okay to just make it a random name, or do i have to match it to the directory path? I'm just greatly confused by the whole situation. Any help you could give would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is a dumb question, but does the folders "net", "baumli" and  "a" exist? (which conform the name of your packages)

Comment: Put Person.java and AcTest.java in Users/myname/Desktop/java/accessControl/net/baumli/a/ - assuming you are compiling with the command line, set your default directory to Users/myname/Desktop/java/accessControl/. Then execute "javac net/baumli/a/AcTest.java". You don't need a classpath variable unless there are other classes somewhere that need to be found.

Answer (score 0):

Just move your package directory above your program directory.

Let your program directory C:\Java\AcTest.java

Then you can create your package directory like
C:\Java\net\baumli\a\Person